# MooTools Tween Stutter/Hiccup

Tags: javascript, animation, mootools

I am doing a rather simple Tween animation using MooTools. The opening animation is perfectly smooth. But then I added the closing animation (opposite of the opening animation), but it seems to stutter/hiccup at the end almost every time.

I tried the following with no success:

- Removed all HTML content from the expanding DIV
- Passing the Bounce settings directly to the Set function instead of using the variable
- Commented the #content animation to be sure there is only 1 animation running
- Commented the addClass and removeClass actions

I can't figure out what's causing the problem. Maybe someone else can have a look…

I put the test-case online here: http://dev.dvrs.eu/mootools/

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
// Set initial Div heights
$('sideBar').setStyle('height', window.getSize().y);
$('sideMenu').setStyle('height', window.getSize().y);

// Set Div heights on Window resize
window.addEvent('resize', function() {
    $('sideBar').setStyle('height', window.getSize().y);
    $('sideMenu').setStyle('height', window.getSize().y);
});

var bounce =  {
    transition: Fx.Transitions.Back.easeOut,
    duration: 500
};

$$('.button.closeMenu').addEvent('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $$('.button').removeClass('active');
    this.addClass('active');

    $('sideMenu').set('tween', bounce);
    $('sideMenu').tween('width', 0);

    $('content').set('tween', bounce);
    $('content').tween('margin-left', 90);
});

$$('.button.menu').addEvent('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $$('.button').removeClass('active');
    this.addClass('active');

    $('sideMenu').set('tween', bounce);
    $('sideMenu').tween('width', 300);

    $('content').set('tween', bounce);
    $('content').tween('margin-left', 390);
});
});
```

### Fiddle with example **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/vtxLG/4/)**

Comment: Yeah that's what I mean. Could have been a bit more clean. When collapsing the menu the last few pixels have a hiccup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transition you are using goes over the values defined as final value in the `.set(property, value);`. So when opening the final width is 300px but the transition/effect goes over that and than soft back to the final value.

This works great when opening because width can be 310px or more and then return to 300px, but when with has a transition under the with 0px, it doesn't work so good. It actually works ok if the final width is 10px (check [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/vtxLG/1/)), but that's not the effect you want.

So my suggestion is to fix it with CSS, or change the transition when closing the sidebar, or use another effect altogether.

Option 1: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vtxLG/) - same transition opening, no easeout closing
Option 2: **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vtxLG/2/)** - same effect as you have but played with CSS and hidded 10px of the sidemenu under the sidebar. (`z-index:3;` on `#sideBar` and `left:80px;width: 10px;` on `#sideMenu`. Also 10px as the final value for the tween.)

To check different transitions at Mootools demo's look **[here](http://mootools.net/demos/?demo=Transitions)**.

Comment: Wow didn't expect the solution to be that simple. After reading your explanation I was like: Of course, you can't have a negative width. Thanks a lot. I am going to use one of your Options as a solution.

Comment: I hope the answer helped. I am not sure if there are other ways to do it, so I posted the answer as a `community wiki` so others can add to it also.